# Analyze concurency::task() API & why do we need this?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx, windows-rt, concurrency-runtime

I'm, trying to understand the syntax of the concurrency::task in the below code snippet.

I'm unable to understand this code snippet syntax. 
How do we analyze this:

> What is "getFileOperation" here. Is it an object of type StorageFile
>   class ?     What does "then" keyword mean here ? There is a "{" after
>   then(....)? I'm unable to analyze this syntax ?

Also why do we need this concurrency::task().then().. Use case ?

```
concurrency::task<Windows::Storage::StorageFile^> getFileOperation(installFolder->GetFileAsync("images\\test.png"));
   getFileOperation.then([](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
   {
      if (file != nullptr)
      {
```

Taken from MSDN [concurrency::task API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx)

```
void MainPage::DefaultLaunch()
{
   auto installFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

   concurrency::task<Windows::Storage::StorageFile^> getFileOperation(installFolder->GetFileAsync("images\\test.png"));
   getFileOperation.then([](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
   {
      if (file != nullptr)
      {
         // Set the option to show the picker
         auto launchOptions = ref new Windows::System::LauncherOptions();
         launchOptions->DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

         // Launch the retrieved file
         concurrency::task<bool> launchFileOperation(Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchFileAsync(file, launchOptions));
         launchFileOperation.then([](bool success)
         {
            if (success)
            {
               // File launched
            }
            else
            {
               // File launch failed
            }
         });
      }
      else
      {
         // Could not find file
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFileOperation` is an object that will return a `StorageFile^` (or an error) at some point in the future. It is a C++ `task<t>` wrapper around the WinRT `IAsyncOperation<T>` object returned from `GetFileAsync`.

The implementation of `GetFileAsync` can (but isn't required to) execute on a different thread, allowing the calling thread to continue doing other work (like animating the UI or responding to user input).

The `then` method lets you pass a continuation function that will be called once the asynchronous operation has completed. In this case, you're passing a lambda (inline anonymous function) which is identified by the `[]` square brackets followed by the lambda parameter list (a `StorageFile^`, the object that will be returned by `GetFileAsync`) and then the function body. This function body will be executed once the `GetFileAsync` operation completes its work sometime in the future.

The code inside the continuation function passed to `then` typically (but not always) executes **after** the code that follows the call to `create_task()` (or in your case the `task` constructor).